# How to save MultipleChoiceField to db

Tags: django, database

I want to create a settings page where a user can select multiple values of skills they have. It will have a main category and then subcategories. I need to save those into my database, so I can query them and show their selected skillset again.

I know how to create the MultipleChoiceField but not how to save them to the database. How would I go on about that?

Forms.py

```
from django import forms


class skills(forms.Form):
    jobs = [
    ('Håndværker', (
            ('Gulv', 'Gulv'),
            ('Væg', 'Væg'),
        )
    ),
    ('Murer', (
            ('Mur', 'Mur'),
            ('blabla', 'blabla'),
        )
    ),
]
    job = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                         choices=jobs)
```

Views.py

```
from .forms import skills

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = skills(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            picked = form.cleaned_data.get('job')
            # do something with your results
    else:
        form = skills
    return render(request, 'settings/index.html', {"form":form})
```

It currently looks like this when the page loads which is good. Next step is just how I would save it to the database, so I can display this again with their previous chosen values.
[image: Example]

Comment: How are you defining it on the model?

Comment: I don't have a model because i'm not sure how to save the MultipleChoiceField in there @Clarity

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any models setup yet, you can look into [django-multiselectfield](https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/), which would store the selected choices "as a CharField of comma-separated values". Then you'd just need to pass those values from your form.

Alternatively you can look into [PostgreSQL's Array field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you have a `Jobs` model and a `Skills` Model. Then have a skills field on the job model which will be a `ManyToManyField` to the Skills model. The form for this can then be autogenerated for you by Django as a `ModelForm`.

```
# Create your models here.
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You can then add them to the db as

```
skill1 = Skill.objects.create(name="Skill One")
skill2 = Skill.objects.create(name="Skill Two")
skill3 = Skill.objects.create(name="Skill Three")
skill4 = Skill.objects.create(name="Skill Four")
job1 = Job.objects.create(name="Job One")
job1.skills.add(skill1)
job1.skills.add(skill2)
job2 = Job.objects.create(name="Job Two")
job2.skills.add(skill3)
job2.skills.add(skill4)
```

Have a form to display

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ["name", "skills"]
```

You can cutomize the form or the template to your linking

Answer (score 0):

in models.py just create the field with CharField

```
from django.db import models
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='')
```

in forms.py just create CHOICE like below

```
class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    YESNO_CHOICES = (('male', 'male'), ('female', 'female'))
    Gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YESNO_CHOICES)
    class Meta():
         model = UserProfileInfo
         fields = ('Gender',)
```

in views.py import this form and display it.

or you can definitely go with

https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/

Comment: The question was referring a MultipleChoiceField, not a ChoiceField